# How to call Shortcode categories for custom post types?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, categories, shortcode

Hi I'm trying to do something rather tricky in my Wordpress Theme I'm more of a designer front-end developer so its a bit of a guess work with php. Anyone have any ideas why this code only displays one slide. I want it to run a slideshow pulling in multipe slides from one category in my theme.

Thanks For your help

```
    //Add Nivo Short Codes
function nivo_slider_function($atts){

   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'posts' => 5,
      'category' => ''
   ), $atts));

 $args = array(
        'numberposts' => -1,
        'orderby' => 'menu_order',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'homepage_slider'
    );

    if ( ! empty( $category ) ) {
        $args['category_name'] = $category;
    }

    $posts = get_posts( $args );

    $homepage_slider  = '<div id="slider">'; //Open the container
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) { // Generate the markup for each Question
        $homepage_slider .= sprintf(('<h3><a href="">%1$s</a></h3><div>%2$s</div>'),
            $post->post_title,
            wpautop($post->post_content)
        );
    }
    $homepage_slider .= '</div>'; //Close the container


   $return_string = '<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">';

   query_posts(array('post_type' => 'homepage_slider', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' , 'showposts' => $posts));

   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();

         $slider_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'homepage-slide', false);
         $target_link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'slide_target_link', true);   
         $return_string .= '<a href="'.$target_link.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="' . $slider_img_src[0] .'" /></a>';

      endwhile;
   endif;
   $return_string .= '</div>';

   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;

}

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('slider-demo', 'nivo_slider_function');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

---

This was the original code taken from a comment on this page. After following the slider tutorial I wanted to use the a shortcode to post it on any page instead of a template however I also wanted different slideshows so was trying above to add in the ability to connect the slideshows with categories.

http://willrees.com/2013/05/create-and-manage-a-nivo-slider-using-wordpress-custom-post-types/

```
function nivo_slider_function($atts){

   extract(shortcode_atts(array(
      'posts' => 5,
   ), $atts));

   $return_string = '<div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">';

   query_posts(array('post_type' => 'homepage_slider', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'order' => 'ASC' , 'showposts' => $posts));

   if (have_posts()) :
      while (have_posts()) : the_post();

         $slider_img_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'homepage-slide', false);
     $target_link = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'slide_target_link', true);

         $return_string .= '<a href="'.$target_link.'" rel="nofollow"><img src="' . $slider_img_src[0] .'" /></a>';

      endwhile;
   endif;
   $return_string .= '</div>';

   wp_reset_query();
   return $return_string;
}

function register_shortcodes(){
   add_shortcode('slider-demo', 'nivo_slider_function');
}

add_action( 'init', 'register_shortcodes');
```

Comment: `query_posts` and `extract` in same function... 2 bad practices at price of one. However, why do you run 2 queries for 'homepage_slider' posts (one with `get_posts` and the other with `query_posts`)?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand php at all so no idea? Its a bit hit  and miss and your comment just means gibberish to my designer eyes??

Comment: Try to explain a bit more in detail what tou want to do. Because looking at your code I can't full understand, because your code is... confused. Seems you are merging 2 sliders, in fact you have 2 divs having `<div id="slider"` or better you *create* 2 divs with `<div id="slider"` but return only one... do you understand what I mean with "confused"?

Comment: Ah Yes I see. I've tried to merge 2 pieces of code shall paste the original in a sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What *surprise* me is that someone on May 2013, write a tutorial using `extract` and `query_posts` in same function.

`extract` is considered a bad practice in PHP in general, and it's usage was abandoned also from WP core (it will no longer be used, but there are still `extract` calls in actual code).

`query_posts` is a bad practice in WordPress world, you can read about it in [the most famous WPSE answer by Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1755/35541) and in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) too (that actually use the picture by Rarst).

Also:

1. your code use the deprecarted argument 'numposts', use 'posts_per_page' instead
2. your code put stuff in html output without escaping with [`esc_*` functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Text_Nodes)
3. your code output images without `alt` attribute that is required for W3C compliant html code

That said, what you want to do is simple a matter of a new [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) called from [`shortcode callback`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode).

```
function nivo_slider_function( $atts ){

   $posts_per_page = isset( $atts['posts'] ) ? $atts['posts'] : -1;

   $args = array(
     'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
     'orderby' => 'menu_order',
     'order' => 'ASC',
     'post_type' => 'homepage_slider'
   );

   if ( isset($atts['category']) && ! empty( $atts['category'] ) ) {
     $args['category_name'] = $atts['category'];
   }

   $query = new WP_Query( $args );

   // nothing to do if we have no posts
   if ( ! $query->have_posts() ) return;

   $slide_format = '<a href="%s" rel="nofollow"><img src="%s" alt="" /></a>';
   $slides = '';
   $slider = '';

   while( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
     $thumbid = get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID);
     // if post has not thumbnail return
     if ( empty( $thumbid ) ) continue;
     $img_src = (array) wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbid, 'homepage-slide' );
     // if a valid image is not foud return
     if ( empty( $img_src ) || ! filter_var( $img_src[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) ) continue;
     $target_link = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'slide_target_link', true );
     // if no valid link is saved in 'slide_target_link' meta, set link to '#'
     if (empty( $target_link ) || ! filter_var( $target_link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL ) ) {
       $target_link = '#';
     }
     $slides .= sprintf( $slide_format, esc_url( $target_link ), esc_url( $img_src[0] ) );
   }

   wp_reset_postdata();

   if ( ! empty( $slides ) ) {
     $id = esc_attr( wp_generate_password( 6, false, false) );
     $slider = "<div id=\"slider_{$id}\" class=\"nivoSlider\">{$slides}</div>";
   }

   return $slider;
}
```

Comment: Wow thanks thanks for that. I think I need a beginners course in php because I don't reaaly understand it. Also what do I put for the shortcode? My shortcode [slider-demo]in my wordpress editor no longer works?

Comment: Sorry if I sound thick. I see you mentioned a short code above but I've no idea how to create it? Even from reading wordpress codex it just makes no sense to me :(

Comment: Oh of course silly me so obvious thanks it works a treat :)

Comment: Is there a way to have multiple sliders on one page?

Comment: @brightmist.co.uk I've edited the code to make use unique IDs for slider div, To have more sliders on a page, just use the same shortcode more than once, using a different category slug each one.